# Multiline Don't work in filebeat 6.7 windows version

Tags: filebeat

I want multiline in one log merge into one record in ES, here is my config part for multiline.

```
multiline.negate: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}'
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
```

But it can't work as expected, It always record each line into ES.

Comment: I am sure reg expression can match my log timestamp

Answer (score 0):

multi-line fields should under filebeat.inputs:
example:

```
filebeat.inputs:
-type: log
...
  multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
...
```